# Cluster label plotting

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

I have cluster labels in one columns and one more column to make comparison or analyze the clusters.

```
import pandas as pd
parties_and_cluesters = pd.DataFrame({'Parties':['A','B','C','C','A','No Party','B','A'],
              'Clusters':['Cluster 2','Cluster 1','Cluster 4','Cluster 4','Cluster 3','Cluster 0','Cluster 3','Cluster 2',]
             })
```

[image]

What is the best way to see the outcome? I thought plotting bar-plot but didn't sound good to me. I want to see if clusters reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to above answer, you may want to display it as stacked. And as I saw from the chat, you can use legend as a seperate part of your plot.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20,10))
parties_and_cluesters.groupby('Clusters')["Parties"].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(10, 5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Question not clear. If wanted to `visualize` and feel nice try `seaborn` `count` plot

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.countplot(x="Clusters", data=parties_and_cluesters)
```

[image]

**Following your comments**

```
parties_and_cluesters.groupby('Clusters')['Parties'].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: I want also visualize parties so that I can see if clusters make sense to me. Although I applied K-Means, unsupervised learning, I wanna see and compare the clusters with the existing column. Have I made my point clearly?

Comment: No, not clear.....

Comment: Parties column has my expected related values for each observation. After clustering I got above labels. Now, I wanna see the distribution of two columns if there is a similarity.

Comment: Similarity in what, it can be argued count plot can show that. Or simply put, what does the plot provided above not show that you want to see?

Comment: For instance, I might wanna see if number of A party seems in **cluster 2** mostly...

Comment: Not sure Iget what you want. Try `parties_and_cluesters.groupby('Clusters')['Parties'].value_counts().unstack().plot.bar()`. Happy to delete my answer to let someone else try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221498/discussion-between-wwnde-and-kahkahkih).